# Replace the "SELECT" text by a custom ones

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to replace the default "Select..." text which comes with the Select input field.

I have several users that an admin need to manage, ideally I would like to change it for something like "Select players for [userX]"

Couldn't find how to deal with that in the readme or in the issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We want some code, please.

Comment: If you get a second and could mark the answer that helped you as accepted, that would be great! Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use the placeholder prop

```
<Select
    ...
    placeholder = `Select players for ${userX}`
    ...
/>
```

http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/
See the second example for a demo

Answer (score 0):

Use the placeholder property:

```
<Select
    placeholder="Select players for [userX]"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks - your answer combined to the second link made me realize it was right under my eyes.